# google books api retrofit

Tags: android, api, retrofit, google-books

I am trying to use the google books API with [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), it is returning an empty result.

this is the url:
https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9781451648546

In Retrofit I have an interface:

```
public interface IServiceEndPoint {
  @GET("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=9781451648546")
  Call<BookList> getBooks();
}
```

in my `webservice class` I have the following method:

```
public void getBooks(final Callback<BookList> callback){
  IServiceEndPoint endPoint = mRetrofit.create(IServiceEndPoint.class);
  Call<BookList> call = endPoint.getBooks();
  call.enqueue(callback);
}
```

in the `activity class` I have the method:

```
private void getBooks(){
  WebserviceHelper.getmInstance().getBooks(new Callback<BookList>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<BookList> call, Response<BookList> response) {
      mBooks = response.body().getResults();
      mBookAdapter.update(mBooks);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BookList> call, Throwable t) {

    }
  });
}
```

I have a Java class **Book** and **BookList**.

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;
public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}

public class BookList extends Book implements Serializable {
    @SerializedName("results")
    private List<Book> results;

    public List<Book> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<Book> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

In the manifest file I added

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET

**mBooks** is returning null value, how could I solve this?
Thank you.

**EDIT:** *shuvro*'s answer helped me correcting the problem. I also forgot to include the volumeInfo in my Book class. My book class looks as followed now:

```
public class Book implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    private VolumeInfo volumeInfo;

    public VolumeInfo getVolumeInfo() {
        return volumeInfo;
    }

    public void setVolumeInfo(VolumeInfo volumeInfo) {
        this.volumeInfo = volumeInfo;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Additionally I created the class volumeInfo:

```
public class VolumeInfo {
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;
    private String publisher;
    private String description;

    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }

    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Check your onFailure method, in Throwable t is probably described your problem. Eg. add t.printStackTrace(); to onFailure method body and check your logcat.

Comment: thank you for the reply, I am not viewing anything in my logcat , I can see that the mBooks value is null in the debug mode

Comment: Did you change your onFailure this way?
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<BookList> call, Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
     }

Comment: yes, i have added it that way.

Comment: Can you post your BookList class?

Comment: Check you POJO, make a Book POJO and a wrapper which has List<Book>

Comment: I have edited my question and posted the Book and BookList class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the two dependency in your gradle file .

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
```

Create a class , lets sats ServiceGenerator , your class should be like this

```
public class ServiceGenerator {


    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Now your declare your interface like this

```
public interface IServiceEndPoint {
  @GET("volumes")
  Call<BookList> getBooks(@Query("q") String id);
}
```

Now in activity or in fragment  , use retrofit in this way

```
IServiceEndPoint serviceEndPoint = ServiceGenerator.createService(IServiceEndPoint.class)

Call<BookList> call = serviceEndPoint.getBooks("9781451648546");

 call.enqueue(new Callback<BookList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BookList> call, Response<BookList> response) {
         //do whatever you want to do 
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BookList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with a question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works to get the ID values from the response, in my java class I also defined a field "title" but this field stays empty in my response , any suggestion to how I can also retrieve the title values?

Answer (score 2):

You `BookList` POJO class has nothing to do with JSON response. It should be something like that:

```
public class BookList { 
    @SerializedName("items")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

You can find all POJO classes for that response [here](https://gist.github.com/kidinov/d35d3e33d199b129307e685839e0d9bc).

Answer (score 1):

I would go on this way and simply follow the way to do usually with retrofit.

```
public interface GBookService {

    @GET("volumes?q=9781451648546")
    Call<BookList> getBooks();

}
```

//

```
public class ApiHelper {

GBookService service;

  public ApiHelper(){
     Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/")
    .build();

    service = retrofit.create(GBookService.class);
  }

 public GBookService getService(){
     return service;
  }

}
```

and where you want to use it :

```
   Call<BookList> call = apiHelper.getService().getBooks();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<BookList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BookList> call, Response<BookList> response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BookList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
```

And BookList, you got the idea I guess

```
public class BookList {

String kind;
int totalItems;
List<Book> items;
...
}
```

(off course adapt with your own code)

Also be sure to have added the internet permission.
You can follow [this](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en) because there is no reasons to not success calling the api. just be sure also your field name are correct and match the one contained in the JSON returned.

Comment: thank you, internet permission was added already, and the fieldname "id" and "title" from the class Book normally should match the field name that json returnes ( i think ), but it still gives no result back in the response